# Understanding Zend DI example from tutorial

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I cannot to understand this example:

```php
// inside a bootstrap somewhere
$di = new Zend\Di\Di();
$di->instanceManager()->setParameters('MyLibrary\DbAdapter', array(
    'username' => $config->username,
    'password' => $config->password
));

// inside each controller
$movieLister = $di->get('MyMovieApp\MovieLister');
foreach ($movieLister as $movie) {
    // iterate and display $movie
}
```

How another part of source code ("inside each controller") knows about $di variable?

Is it not completed example? Can anyone show how I can to use DI container in my controllers?

Tutorial page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.di.quick-start.html

Comment: Don't use `Zend\Di` use [`Zend\ServiceManager`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html)

Comment: ServiceManager is bad practice because it is Service Locator, antipattern.

Comment: This isn't true. Using the `getServiceLocator()` is a bad practice. The Service-Manager in general is NOT a bad practice. It's basically the same as your DI just with another name and much easier to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples in Zend Framework 2 tutorials describe how to use particular component **outside of whole framework environment** to let you understand better its features.

One of basic ideas of Zend's developers was  always to create a package of independent libraries (with only some dependencies between them when needed) to let you choose which part of framework you want to use. For example you could take `DI` class and use it in some other framework. It would work fine. When they say

*inside controller*

they mean

*not necessarily our controller you any others too*

Please note that [`ZendSkeletonApplication`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) is just an example of use for ZF2, but it doesn't actually belongs to the framework itself.

So the way that you will get `Di` object in any place depends on your application architecture. If you think in context of using whole ZF2, then you probably won't create `Di` object on your own at all. `Di` will be used by `ServiceLocator` which will let you manage your services (objects, factories etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this one to get a perceptive for a future research :

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Services-Instances-Dependencies-in-ZF2-td4584632.html

You also should check out :

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Roughly speaking , ServiceManager in Zend/Mvc/Application does lots of Di work.

Comment: I read about ServiceManager, but I cannot understand example from tutorial. I understand how to use ServiceManager :)

Answer (score 0):

The example is missing the indication on how to configure the controller to have `MyMovieApp\MovieLister` injected into it, rather than invoking `Zend\Di\Di::get()`; the latter assumes that the DIC itself has been injected into the controller, which is indeed an anti pattern.

To be honest, that's actually a downside of the current default implementation of ZF2 mvc controllers, which have the `ServiceManager` (which has superseded `Di` mainly for performance reasons) injected into them. This issue has been discussed extensively and it will very likely be dealt with in ZF3.

For the time being, just use the `ServiceManager`, ignore the fact that it is injected into controllers, and use constructor injection inside concrete service factories. That is the best acknowledged way to do IoC in ZF2 at the moment, it's solid and by no means a bad practice.